# Powershell http request forces out of fullscreen applications

Tags: powershell

My goal is to have this code constantly running in the background of windows from startup. However when in fullscreen applications I have found the HTTP get command causes fullscreen applications to tab out to the desktop every few seconds. Does anyone know how I may solve this issue?

```
powershell -windowstyle hidden {
While($true){

$message = (Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://ptsv2.com/t/gx6b6-1600095415#").Content
Set-Clipboard -Value $message
Sleep -s 0.2

}
}
```

Comment: I can not recreate this issue. Where is this script running from exactly?
When i run it in ISE and turn on fullscreen games, Video Apps, and Web Browers. I Do not have the issue where it takes me out of full screen.

Comment: Try adding `-UseBasicParsing` to the `Invoke-WebRequest` call

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen adding -UseBasicParsing worked. Thanks for the help!